# How to add "Kind" settings to "/.kube/config" file?

Tags: configuration, kubeadm, kind

I have installed `kubeadm` previously and configured it using `kubeadm --init` and the configs are inside `/.kube/config` file by now. I recently installed `kind` and want to know how should I configure it?

My goal is to using `kind` to work with `kubernetes` locally alongside `skaffold`. It seems images can't be pulled directly from a local storage to `kubeadm` using `skaffold` and we need something like `kind` in between.

Answer (score 0):

I assume by this time that you've discovered that just running `kind create cluster` that you will get new entries in the config file.